# Missing Keys: title

Tags: laravel

I installed Bagisto and everything run smoothly until I added Laravel AliExpress Dropshipping.[image]

There's error :

Webkul\Ui\Exceptions\ActionKeyException
Missing Keys: title (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bagisto/packages/Webkul/Dropship/src/Resources/views/admin/products/index.blade.php)

What does Missing Keys: title means

```
    @extends('admin::layouts.content')

@section('page_title')
    {{ __('dropship::app.admin.products.title') }}
@stop

@section('content')

<h1>
                    {{ __('dropship::app.admin.products.title') }}
                </h1>

<div class="page-action">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" style="display: none">
                    {{ __('dropship::app.admin.products.import-btn-title') }}
                </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: it means title doesn't exist in dropship::app.admin.products translation file

Comment: 'products' => [
            'title' => 'AliExpress Products',

Found this in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bagisto/packages/Webkul/Dropship/src/Resources/lang/en/app.php

Comment: try __('dropship::app.products.title')

Comment: still same error. dropship::app.admin.products.title does exist in app.php

<?php

return [
    'admin' => [
'products' => [
            'title' => 'AliExpress Products',
     ]
    ]
];

?>

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Bagisto Bulk Upload extension. To fix it I added the 'title' key to both addAction at extension's DataGrid class.

```
    public function prepareActions() {

    $this->addAction([
        'type' => 'Edit',
        'method' => 'GET', // use GET request only for redirect purposes
        'route' => 'marketplace.bulkupload.profile.edit',
        'icon' => 'icon pencil-lg-icon',
        'title' => ''
    ]);

    $this->addAction([
        'type' => 'Delete',
        'method' => 'GET', // use GET request only for redirect purposes
        'route' => 'marketplace.bulkupload.profile.delete',
        'icon' => 'icon trash-icon',
        'title' => ''
    ]);

    $this->enableAction = true;
}
```

[Source](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/bagisto/bagisto-bulk-upload/55)